# WPF - How to get SelectedIndex of a ComboBox defined in a DataTemplate?

Tags: wpf, mvvm, datatemplate

In my WPF app I have a data import function which imports data from an Excel file into a database.

In order to allow user to map the columns from their Excel file to the columns in my database table I am displaying the list of Excel columns in a `ComboBox` next to database table column names allowing the user to select the matching Excel column from the `ComboBox`.

This is displayed in a `ListBox` with each item containing a `ComboBox` and a `TextBlock`.

The `ListBox` is Data Bound to a `Dictionary<ColumnsClass, List<string>>` where `ColumnsClass` is a simple object containing database column names and other details and the `List<string>` is just a list of column names found in the Excel file. In order to display the `List<string>` in the `ComboBox` I have a  DataTemplate defined as such:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="ColumnList">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"></ColumnDefinition>
    <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"></ColumnDefinition>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
       <ComboBox Grid.Column="0" ItemsSource="{Binding Value, Mode=OneWay}">
   </ComboBox>
   <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding Key, Mode=OneWay}"/>
    </Grid>
</DataTemplate>
```

Once the user maps the Excel columns to database column names and starts the import I need to be able to get the database column name and the matching 'ComboBox' 'SelectedIndex' value of each item in the `ListBox` but the each item in the ItemsSource is actually a `KeyValuePair<ColumnsClass, List<string>>` so I don't see how to get the 'ComboBox' 'SelectedIndex' value while iterating through the `ListBox.Items` collection...

Any ideas?

Comment: Note that you don't have to specify width of `ColumnDefinition` in this case, since `1*` is the default value.

Comment: Right, this is modified code, there are more columns defined and `1*` is not the value in actual code...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use the `Dictionary` just as a `IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<ColumnsClass, List<string>>>`, you could create a custom class to hold the two values and add a value specifying user's choice:

```cs
class ViewModel
{
    public ColumnClass ColumnClass { get; set; }
    public List<string> ColumnNames { get; set; }
    public string SelectedColumn { get; set; }
}
```

Then use `List<ViewModel>` (or any other collection) instead of your `Dictionary` and bind to `SelectedColumn` in your XAML:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="ColumnList">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition />
            <ColumnDefinition />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ComboBox Grid.Column="0" ItemsSource="{Binding ColumnNames, Mode=OneWay}"
            SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedColumn}" />
        <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding ColumnClass, Mode=OneWay}"/>
    </Grid>
</DataTemplate>
```

If, for some reason, you didn't want to create a separate class and you're on .Net 4, you could use `Tuple<ColumnClass, List<string>, string>` instead of `ViewModel`.

Comment: Looks like a good solution will give it a shot tomorrow and let you know if it worked... thanks.

Comment: Just brain cramping yday trying to get around what was the wrong approach in the first place. Thanks.